# How to expose a c service / cpp service easily and securely

Tags: c++, c, nginx, fastcgi

I want to host a cpp service as a executable file and able to track the log, handle the exception and able to handle high load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try c-sevice-interface https://github.com/Taymindis/c-service-interface

This is a small bridge engine which can handle high load of request, any segfault will not break the engine, it will catch and free the thread, it is built on top NGINX, FCGI. You can setup the proxy, load balance, authentication via NGINX before reach to your interface.

The link shown as below is a wiki to Guide you how to startup from scratch.

https://github.com/Taymindis/fcgi-function/wiki/How-to-build-a-cpp-service-on-c-service-interface